# Replace subexpression with a variable

Tags: expression-manipulation

```
r = (a - b + d)/(-a + b + c)
```

Need replace (a-b) with z 
to get this result:

```
(z + d)/(-z + c)
```

I have tried Replace, ReplaceAll, /., but nothing seems to be working.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your expression contains both `a-b` and `-a+b`. You can do either

```
r /. {a - b -> z, -a + b -> -z}
```

or

```
r /. {a -> z + b}
```